# Ember.js with Firebase backend: change Firebase's auto-generated model IDs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a personal website with Ember.js and Firebase (EmberFire) as the backend. I've got Firebase connected and I can createRecords and such, and then view the records in the Firebase console.

I'm building my own post system for my website for personal posts and whatnot. I would like to have a dynamic route for my posts at `/posts/:post_id`, where `:post_id` is the dasherized title of the post. I've been following the Ember tutorial and already have all the attributes I need (like a dasherized title) in my model. However, whenever I create a record and send the data to the Firebase database, Firebase automatically generates a post id like so:

```
posts
 -KP3SRMcfGCXW1hz-c1W
 -KP3a-6nr9C_gqPMTnFO
 -KP53U2pxOZw1gCewBXM
 -KPAde4QmamjrrNpVhhn
 -KPAeXaxty4p5uWbBvE8
 -KPAetgYyKFZMVCl9h9l
 -KPAh0JZt6GvLqhpEnIG
 -KPAh8vrKNaPLYZGbkvq
```

So if I have a post called "hello first post", I can't go to `/posts/hello-first-post`, but if that post has ID `-KPAh8vrKNaPLYZGbkvq`, I could go to `/posts/-KPAh8vrKNaPLYZGbkvq` and it would work. I've already generated the dynamic route which is why the latter option works.

I am wondering how I can change this so that I can have the dynamic route for posts NOT be the auto-generated id by Firebase.

For example, I want this to work:

```
{{link-to post.title "post" post.dasherizedTitle}}
```

I already have a post route which routes to /posts/:post_id, so the link-to helper is generating the correct link. But there is nothing there because Firebase has it's auto-generated post ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can use put instead of post on firebase, put will not have the auto generated data, push will have auto-generated id, because its an array